# Scoring a ranking question

Tags: ranking

I’m tasked with writing exam questions and I want to include a ranking question.
The idea is to have students rank 5 items in the correct order. When scoring the question, I want to do partial grading meaning the closer the students’ ranking is to the correct answer the more points they receive (max. 5 points).

What correlation method / formula would I best use to calculate the scores?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Kendall's Tau (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient)), because it doesn't penalize sublists which are simply in the wrong part in the sequence (but in the right order as a sublists; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2492954/distance-between-two-permutations.)
An example in R:

```
> library(arrangements)    # to get all possible permutations
> library(VGAM)            # to compute Kendall's Tau
> x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)        # right order
> X <- permutations(x)     # right order (the first row) then 119 wrong orders
> tau <- rep(NA, 120)      # init
> for (i in 1:120) tau[i] <- kendall.tau(x, X[i,])
```

You get 11 possible values:

```
> unique(tau)
 [1]  1.0  0.8  0.6  0.4  0.2  0.0 -0.2 -0.4 -0.6 -0.8 -1.0
```

the best is 1 for the right order:

```
> kendall.tau(x, c(1,2,3,4,5))
[1] 1
```

then 0.8 if only one number is in the wrong place and sequence,

```
> kendall.tau(x, c(1,2,3,5,4))
[1] 0.8
> kendall.tau(x, c(2,1,3,4,5))
[1] 0.8
```

finally -1 when all is wrong:

```
> kendall.tau(x, c(5,4,3,2,1))
[1] -1
```

You could give 5 points when Tau is 1, then 4 for 0.8 or 0.6, 3 for 0.4 or 0.2, 2 for 0 or -0.2, 1 for 0.4 or -0.6, 0 for -0.8 or -1.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergio! That was very helpful!

Comment: @casep You're welcome, happy to be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at "[derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#:%7E:text=In%20combinatorial%20mathematics%2C%20a%20derangement,appears%20in%20its%20original%20position.&text=The%20number%20of%20derangements%20of,n%2Dth%20de%20Montmort%20number.)".

The 'best' criterion depends on what you consider an 'almost correct' ranking.
are `21345` and `52341` equally bad because each has 3 elements in the correct position
or is the second one worse because mixing up `1` and `5` is more serious than mixing up `1` and `2`? @Sergio's answer (+1) makes good sense, but if having elements in correct
position is of primary importance then you ought to use that. And it's an easy criterion to score. In R,

```
sum(1:5==c(2,1,3,4,5))
[1] 3
sum(1:5==c(5,2,3,4,1))
[1] 3
sum(1:5==c(2,3,4,5,1))
[1] 0
sum(1:5==c(1,4,3,2,5))
[1] 3
sum(1:5==c(5,4,3,2,1))
[1] 1
```

Comment: That's a good point you mention! I haven't really thought about that. 
I think in my case it should make a difference, meaning mixing up 1 and 5 should result in a lower score than mixing up 1 and 2.